# Eliminating redundancy in recursive factorial function in C

Tags: c, recursion, redundancy

we all know this implementation of factorial function:

```
double fact(double i) {
    if (i == 1 || i == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else
        return i * fact(i - 1);
}
```

I want to eliminate the redundancy so the execution time will be lower. I tried using a lookup array but couldn't do properly. How can I eliminate redundancy so the code will run faster?

Comment: @EugeneSh.yes you are right I edited my quesiton but Its not really my problem.

Comment: The only redundancy is the check for `i==1`. This case can be handled by recursion. But is is more of optimization though.

Comment: @EugeneSh.thank you for your replies! My teacher asked this: How would you modify (i.e., rewrite) the function fact so as to eliminate the
redundant recursive calls and reduce the number S of recursive calls?

What should I do? I am a CSE student (year 2) I have been working on this question for hours by now

Comment: I do not see any redundancy here. There is exactly `i` calls (+/-1). There is no way to compute the factorial in less than `O(i)`.

Comment: Surely, you can "skip" each second `i` by doing something like `i * (i-1) * factorial(i-2)`, but then why not do `-3`? Or unroll it completely? I don't think this is what was meant.

Comment: There are [tricks](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/efficient-factorials-calculation/), but the problem is not well stated. On 64 bits integers, the fastest function is probably a look up table anyway

Comment: @EugeneSh.you cant do -3 because It won't work for input: 2. I guess this is the answer. Thank you for your replies! It did work for my teacher

Comment: Why use `double`? What if the user asks for `fact(3.5)`?

Comment: Please don't remove your post when your question is solved! The value in this site lies in that questions are useful for future visitors, too.

Comment: Removing the content of your question is considered vandalizing. Please don't do that. Rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you mix redundancy with recursion :) To eliminate, you can just use for loop

```
result = 1;
for(int x=1; x<i; x++)
  result*=x
```

Comment: no I mean the function will be recursive but I want to reduce its call count.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Can you check my reply to the other question? What should I do

Answer (score 0):

I found this approach online, hope it helps. This makes use of dynamic programming.

```
Begin
   fact(int n):
      Read the number n
      Initialize
      i = 1, result[1000] = {0}
      result[0] = 1
      for i = 1 to n
         result[i] = I * result[i-1]
   Print result
End
```

Refer to this link for more information regarding this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-find-factorial-of-a-number-using-dynamic-programming

If you are looking for something with recursion, this was the best according to me.

```
int factorial(int n) {
    if (n>=1)
        return n*factorial(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

If you find something else, please do let us know.

Comment: The recursive variant is not conceptually different from the OP's

Comment: That's true, all I did was just reduce a check in the if condition. Complexity wise it is the same.